# Automake test script dependencies

Tags: automake

I have a test script run on `make check` set up like so:

```
TESTS = test.py
```

But `test.py` depends on another file being built. How do I specify that dependency to automake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a plain *make* dependency:

```
TESTS = test.py
test.py: that_other_file

that_other_file:
        echo Hi > $@     # remember to use a TAB before the action as usual
```